# Quadrature in quantum optics

Tags: terminology, quantum-optics

I am reading a chapter about Squeezed state, and came across this word, quadrature, which I have never seen before in the book. Here is the quote from that chapter.

" A general class of minumum-uncertainty states are known as squeezed states. In general, a squeezed stat may have less noise in one quadrature than a coherent state. [...]"

I have looked up on the internet and found explanations to be very confusing. Could you help explain to me the meaning of quadrature?

Comment: Have you seen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_phase_space and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state ?

Comment: I have. However, after reading all of these and other more, I cannot make out the physical meaning of Quadrature. That baffle me.

Comment: I feel your pain. "Quadrature" is used all over the place in several subfields of physics and engineering and it's vaguely defined at best. In this case we can definitely be more specific. Are you familiar with the operators $X = a + a^\dagger$ and $Y = a - a^\dagger$?

Comment: One meaning of "quadrature" is a numeric integration scheme (trapazoid, Simpson's rule, splines etc), but that does not seem to apply here.

Comment: @dmckee Indeed, quadrature some times means "integration" but that's completely different from here where it roughly means "the two orthogonal components of a single frequency oscillation, i.e. $\sin$ and $\cos$."

Comment: @DanielSank, Sorry for late reply. I am indeed familiar with these operators. With the explanation given by $WetSavannaAnimal\textrm{ }ask\textrm{ }Rod\textrm{ }Vance$, I have a better understanding on the matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you've seen, the word quadrature is overladen with many, none-too-precise meanings.

Here the "quadratures" loosely refer to the position and momentum observables:

$$\hat{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(a + a^\dagger)$$
$$\hat{p} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\,(a - a^\dagger)$$

where $a,\,a^\dagger$ are the lowering/ raising operators and I've normalized the two observables so that $[\hat{x},\,\hat{p}] = i\,\mathrm{id}$. These two (or measurements coming from these observables) are loosely called "quadratures" because, for a coherent / squeezed state $\psi$ the mean measurements $\langle\psi|\hat{x}|\psi\rangle$ and $\langle\psi|\hat{p}|\psi\rangle$ are sinusoidally-with-time varying quantities which are in *phase quadrature*, *i.e.* a quarter cycle out of phase.

The squeezed states are the most general states that saturate (*i.e.* actually achieve equality in) the Heisenberg product. A coherent state is a special case for which the normalized momentum and position uncertainties are equal, and their preroduct is the uncertainty bound $\hbar/2$. A squeezed state has the same uncertainty product, but the uncertainty on one of position or momentum measurements is smaller than the uncertainty on the other, so one achieves smaller uncertainty than for the corresponding coherent state at the expense of the other. One can generalize the above comments for any "generalized" position and momentum, defined, for any $\phi\in\mathbb{R}$, by:

$$\hat{x} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(e^{i\,\phi}\,a + e^{-i\,\phi}\,a^\dagger)$$
$$\hat{p} = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\,(e^{i\,\phi}\,a - e^{-i\,\phi}\,a^\dagger)$$

which are conjugate in the QM sense of fulfilling the CCR and the means of whose measurements vary sinusoidally with time, again, in phase quadrature.

Comment: In case you know, could you please add an explanation why "phase quadrature" signifies "a quarter cycle out of phase"? Thank you!

Comment: @Daniel I'm afraid you'll need to ask the electrical engineers that one. The full OED simply tells me that electrical engineers began using the word for a quarter cycle out of phase, and the word's original meaning was of "squaring" - referring to the idea of finding a square of equal area to a circle and, by extrapolation, the finding of areas under curves, thus another word for *integration*. "Gaussian quadrature" is how the mostly obsolete word survives in this sense. This may also explain 90 degrees out of phase: the integral of a sinusoid is 90 degrees lagging the original.

Comment: @Daniel you actually don't need to talk to electrical engineers for this. If you just think about the position and momentum of a harmonic oscillator you'll find that they're both sinusoidal in time and exactly one quarter cycle out of phase as already discussed by WetSavannaAnimal.

Comment: @DanielSank I think Daniel was asking why a quarter cycle phase lag is called "quadrature"; my *guess* is that its because the integral of a sinusoid lags the original by a quarter cycle, but there's no reference for that in the OED, or anything else I could find.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Ah. That one is a mystery.

Comment: @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance Thanks for the OED perspective.  That's the first time I've seen an explanation for the meaning as integration.  Interesting.

Comment: @garyp It's relatively common. For example, you can say a 1D problem in newtonian mechanics "reduces to quadratures" if conservation of energy lets you express the solution in terms of an integral, or its inverse, even if you then cannot solve that integral in any useful sense.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Yes, it's very common.  Software integrators are often have it in the name.  What is not common is understanding the origin of the usage in this context.

Comment: @garyp My understanding is that the origin is simple - integration means finding the sides of a square with the same area as a given shape. (Hence e.g. "la cuadratura del círculo", squaring the circle in Spanish.)

Answer (score 2):

Quadrature has a very clear and precise meaning in Quantum Mechanis. Some quantities don't commute, i.e., you cannot measure both of them with unlimeted precision. This is related to Heisenbeg unsertainty. 
Let's put this two variables in the Cartesian plan and call this observables as X and Y.. if X is position then Y is momentum. If X is electric field then Y is the magnetic field, and so on.
The fact is that  in some measurements the instrument doesn't meadures exactly X, but a linear combination of X and Y. Let's call it X'. This is one "quadrature" and can be represented as an axis in the Cartesian plan that crises the origin. The complementary quadrature (Y') will be also a linear combination of X and Y and can be also represented as an axis. The X' and Y' are a new set of quadratures and look like a rotation of the original axis X and Y. Indeed, there are infinite quadratures for any given set of X and Y variables that do not commute.